# Copy/Replace/Open MS Access DataBase in VB as a User

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So basically I made a FamilyTree Program using MS Access DataBase. I want the user to be able to 'Export'(Copy) the Access File and be able to 'Import'(Replace) it in the program after it's already built. I tried looking for this but all I get is how to do these things as a programmer and not a user.
If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful :)

Comment: Which type of file do you want to export and import?

Comment: The MS Access DataBase (.accdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the connection to the file and do a simple file copy.

To restore, copy the backup file overwriting the current file.

Comment: Are there any tutorials you could point me to .... I've honestly never done anything like that before :/

Comment: There are too many to mention. Just bing/google on the keywords.

Comment: Okay .. I did what you said .. And it worked (Thanks!) .. But now the program uses the data from the old MS Access File when I replace it. IT doesn't take in the new File's Data until I close the program and open it again :/

Comment: Somewhere in your code or in a setting you have a path to your database hard coded. You will need to allow the user to point to the new location and fix the path being used in your connectionstring.

Comment: When I replace the access file the new file is named and put in the same location as the old one, there is no need to change the path in the connection string since there is no new location.

Comment: "the program uses the data from the old MS Access File" - yep, it is probably cached so it doesn't have to read again and again the same data. If you refresh or close and reopen the connection, the "new" data should be present.